# Upper and bottom <td> expanding in Html template

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email, newsletter

I am coding a html email, the problem is that I have a black border around my table, when I slcide psd make it no image and set background color like this

```
<td width="640" height="2" colspan="16" style="background-color:#666666;">
```

left and right `<td>` look ok in html and the email client, but the upper and bottom one are bit expanded,  see attached image for this

This is in my laptop upper `<td>`
[image]

and this is how it looks in emails

[image]

code is simple as

```
<td width="640" height="2" colspan="16" style="background-color:#666666;">
  </td>
```

What's the problem with it? Please help ..!

Answer (score 1):

Outlook expands all table cells to a minimum of 19px high. This is something you'll need to work around in html email design. One method is to create a 20px high image that has your 2px border across the bottom.

Comment: this problem is with browsers as chrome /Firefox etc

Comment: Are you using valign on your containing table? it could be that everything is vertically centering. Hard to tell without more of your code...

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS and see how it works:

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: is that allowe  in email template ?

Comment: You can use it, but you need to be aware that gmail and some other clients will strip anything that is not inline stylings, and completely remove the head part of your html. Outlook and a few others  have no problem rendering it.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
style="border-collapse:collapse;"
```

to your

```
<table>
```

like this

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
```

Comment: i am using  <td> that is not border

Answer (score 0):

Your table has borders, as is the standard. This is my snippet for all of my tables' structure-

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640" style="border-collapse:collapse; padding:0; margin:0px;">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td align="left">

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a spacer gif in your TD ?

If yes, the trick is simple :

```
<img src="SPACER" border="0" style="display:block;" height="x" width="y" alt="" />
```

This will collapse the white space around your images. Make sure you set the same height to your td and img also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to add some position property

Try `position: absolute`